# Unable to reset password for On-Premises using Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph for resetting users' password. I'm able to do for the users with domain.onmicrosoft.com but not with domain.com users who are in On-Prem active directory. On-Prem has latest version on Azure AD Connect and password write back is enabled. On Azure, password reset has been enabled at AAD. I'm getting the below error when I'm trying to update the password or display name or any other properties

Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Unable to update the specified properties for on-premises mastered Directory Sync objects or objects currently undergoing migration.

Answer (score 0):

To reset the password for on-premise, you need to enable `Self service password reset`in the Azure portal.

[image]

And you also need to make sure the "write back passwords to onprmises directory" is enabled.

[image]

Comment: It is done, but we are still getting error while updating user profile with new password.

Comment: Hi Naveen, I know this is an old post, but I'm running into a similar issue. Could you please explain how you managed to get it working?